# history of programming language names?

Tags: c, programming-languages, lisp, history

do anyone know the history of programming language names? where they come from?
a,b,c, java, python, scheme, prolog, ada, fortran, algol, cobol, assembly, pascal, lisp, perl, haskell, php, javascript, c#, ruby, c++ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Often the name is inspired by a previous lagnuage (that's the case of C++, which derives from C, which in turn has been named after B ...), but more often language inventor just picked a name he was liking for some reason.

Maybe you could be interested in the [genealogy of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest searching Wikipedia :)

But for Python I can answer the question, it comes from "Monty Python", the entertainment/comedy group - not the animal. In Python examples often there are references to Monty Python like `"SPAMSPAMSPAM"` and `"NI NI NI"`.

Comment: this is not an answer at all